# Magento 1.7 Index Error on product description update

Tags: magento, indexing

when trying to update Magento 1.7 product descriptions, we get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
in /app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Event.php on line 167' 
in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245 
Stack trace: 
#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Event.php(167): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/var/www/magent...', 167, Array) 
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Event.php(199): Mage_Index_Model_Event->_mergeNewDataRecursive(false, Array) 
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Event.php(67): Mage_Index_Model_Event->mergePreviousData(Array) 
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(423): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Event->_beforeSave(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event)) 
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Mode in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 245
```

Any ideas, what is going wrong?

Thanks for your help

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, using a wrong store id.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1);
```